Mac Studio (M2 Max) frequently wakes (incl. displays) without cause
I'm trying to figure out why my new Mac Studio has serious issues staying asleep; it frequently wakes up, including waking displays, with any apparent cause.
I've had it a week now, and here's some data to show various statuses in the last week (all computer data is from pmset -g log):

There are eight "rows" on this plot. In each row:

The top line (which lines up with the integer, and is only seen at the end of the second row and beginning of third row and once more briefly later) indicates the computer is off.
The next line, black, indicates the system is in "Deep Idle"
The next line, dark blue, indicates the system is in "Dark Wake"
The next line, blue, indicates the system is Awake
The next line, magenta" indicates the displays are on
The next line shows when I was and was not home in the last week (green=home, grey=not). Also, from roughly 10pm to 6am I was asleep. This is included to show there are many activities which are when I'm not even home (and the room with the computer is closed and inaccessible to others/pets).

Above each section are symbols indicating the wake events in the system log.

Magenta triangle facing down corresponds to a "Deep Idle" to "Dark Wake" transition as a result of User Activity.
Magenta triangle facing up corresponds to a transition to "Awake" (from either Dark Wake or Deep Idle) as a result of User Activity.
Brown little thingies pointing up and down are the same, but not labeled as being the result of User Activity.

The first day after I got it (-6) I believe the very long stretch of wake events was caused by my Yubikey being plugged in (wtf?). However, there are a lot of wake events while I'm not even home and a lot of events while I was home but didn't do anything to wake the computer (which aren't annotated here on the plot because... I didn't record them all, though it's safe to say the ones over night (e.g. -2) were not me sleepwalking and wiggling the mouse).
Here's the log around one of the wake/sleep events on 3 October (-2):
2024-10-03 01:39:40 -0600 Assertions            PID 418(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context3845.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:12:48  id:0x0x50000a0bb [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:40 -0600 Assertions            PID 418(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context3845.preventuseridlesleep" 00:12:48  id:0x0x10000a0ba [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:40 -0600 Assertions            PID 418(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context3859.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:12:48  id:0x0x50000a0d7 [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:40 -0600 Assertions            PID 418(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context3859.preventuseridlesleep" 00:12:48  id:0x0x10000a0d6 [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:40 -0600 Assertions            PID 418(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context3853.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:12:48  id:0x0x50000a0cb [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:40 -0600 Assertions            PID 457(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd0000a0e9 [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:40 -0600 Assertions            PID 418(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context3853.preventuseridlesleep" 00:12:48  id:0x0x10000a0ca [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:40 -0600 Assertions            PID 418(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context3858.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:12:48  id:0x0x50000a0d5 [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
<a bunch of stuff like the previous/next line was removed to fit in StackExchange character limit>       
2024-10-03 01:39:40 -0600 Assertions            PID 418(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context3854.preventuseridlesleep" 00:12:48  id:0x0x10000a0cc [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:40 -0600 Assertions            PID 418(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context3862.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:12:48  id:0x0x50000a0dd [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:40 -0600 Assertions            PID 418(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context3862.preventuseridlesleep" 00:12:48  id:0x0x10000a0dc [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:40 -0600 Assertions            PID 457(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd0000a0e9 [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:40 -0600 Assertions            PID 418(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context3820.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:13:32  id:0x0x50000a09b [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:40 -0600 Assertions            PID 418(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context3820.preventuseridlesleep" 00:13:32  id:0x0x10000a09a [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
<a bunch of stuff like the previous/next line was removed to fit in StackExchange character limit>       
2024-10-03 01:39:40 -0600 Assertions            PID 418(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context3807.preventuseridlesleep" 00:13:32  id:0x0x10000a080 [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:40 -0600 Assertions            PID 418(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context3822.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:13:31  id:0x0x50000a09f [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:40 -0600 Assertions            PID 418(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context3822.preventuseridlesleep" 00:13:31  id:0x0x10000a09e [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:41 -0600 Assertions            PID 339(powerd) TurnedOn UserIsActive "com.apple.powermanagement.kernel.useractive AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:kIOHIDSystemActivityTickle nxEvent: 0x" 00:00:00  id:0x0x900008ed0 [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:41 -0600 Assertions            PID 394(WindowServer) Created PreventSystemSleep "com.apple.WindowServer.PUIDS" 00:00:00  id:0x0x70000a0ea [System: PrevSleep DeclUser kCPU kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:41 -0600 Assertions            PID 339(powerd) TurnedOn UserIsActive "com.apple.powermanagement.kernel.useractive AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:kIOHIDSystemActivityTickle nxEvent: 0x" 00:00:00  id:0x0x900008ed0 [System: PrevSleep DeclUser kCPU kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:41 -0600 Notification          Display is turned on                                                                  
2024-10-03 01:39:41 -0600 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt DataFrame ARPT/UserActivity Assertion Using AC (Charge:0%) 67 secs   
2024-10-03 01:39:41 -0600 WakeDetails           DriverReason:SMC.OutboxNotEmpty - DriverDetails:                           
DriverReason:smc.70070000 - DriverDetails:                                 
DriverReason:wifibt - DriverDetails:                                       
DriverReason:DataFrame - DriverDetails:08004500017e0d79400033068984113990580a0103eb1467d0e5c731b77
DriverReason:ARPT - DriverDetails:                                         
2024-10-03 01:39:41 -0600 HibernateStats        hibmode=0 standbydelaylow=0 standbydelayhigh=0                                        700           
2024-10-03 01:39:41 -0600 WakeTime              WakeTime: 0.883 sec                                                                   
2024-10-03 01:39:41 -0600 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Sleep notifications: [AppleDCPDPTXRemotePortProxy driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(66 ms)] 
2024-10-03 01:39:41 -0600 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [RTBuddy(ANS2) driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(79 ms)] [AppleDCPDPTXRemotePortProxy driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(73 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(77 ms)] [usb-drd1-port-hs driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(88 ms)] [usb-drd3-port-hs driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(103 ms)] [AppleT6020PCIe driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(291 ms)] [usb-drd1-port-ss driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 3)(222 ms)] [usb-drd3-port-ss driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 3)(208 ms)] [IOPP driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(201 ms)] [pci-bridge2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(201 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(490 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(492 ms)] [AppleEmbeddedUSBXHCIASMedia3142 driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(330 ms)] [AppleEthernetAquantiaAqtion113 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(154 ms)]           
2024-10-03 01:39:41 -0600 Assertions            PID 339(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.acwakelinger" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd0000a0ee [System: PrevIdle PrevSleep DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:39:42 -0600 Assertions            Summary- [System: PrevIdle PrevSleep DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp] Using AC          
2024-10-03 01:39:42 -0600 Assertions            PID 394(WindowServer) Released PreventSystemSleep "com.apple.WindowServer.PUIDS" 00:00:01  id:0x0x70000a0ea [System: PrevIdle DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:40:11 -0600 Notification          Display is turned off                                                                 
2024-10-03 01:40:11 -0600 Assertions            PID 339(powerd) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "Powerd - Prevent sleep while display is on" 00:00:30  id:0x0x10000a0eb [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:40:11 -0600 Assertions            PID 339(powerd) Summary UserIsActive "com.apple.powermanagement.kernel.useractive AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:kIOHIDSystemActivityTickle nxEvent: 0x" 00:00:30  id:0x0x900008ed0 [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:40:11 -0600 Assertions            PID 339(powerd) Summary InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.acwakelinger" 00:00:30  id:0x0xd0000a0ee [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:40:25 -0600 Assertions            PID 418(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context3893.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:00:43  id:0x0x50000a10c [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
<a bunch of stuff like the previous/next line was removed to fit in StackExchange character limit>       
2024-10-03 01:40:25 -0600 Assertions            PID 418(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context3941.preventuseridlesleep" 00:00:42  id:0x0x10000a151 [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:40:26 -0600 Assertions            PID 339(powerd) TimedOut InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.acwakelinger" 00:00:45  id:0x0xd0000a0ee [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:40:26 -0600 Assertions            Summary- [System: DeclUser kDisp] Using AC          
2024-10-03 01:40:43 -0600 Assertions            PID 339(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.darkwakelinger" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd0000a18d [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:40:44 -0600 Assertions            Summary- [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp] Using AC          
2024-10-03 01:40:48 -0600 Assertions            PID 339(powerd) TimedOut InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.darkwakelinger" 00:00:05  id:0x0xd0000a18d [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-10-03 01:40:48 -0600 Assertions            Summary- [System: DeclUser kDisp] Using AC          
Sleep/Wakes since boot at 2024-10-02 19:31:36 -0600 :39   Dark Wake Count in this sleep cycle:5

There are also night time wake events from ARPT/, rtc/UserActivity, ARPT/HID
2024-10-03 04:50:18 -0600 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to NUB.SPMI0Sw3IRQ nub-spmi0.0x02 rtc/UserActivity Assertion Using AC (Charge:0%) 67 secs   
2024-10-03 04:50:18 -0600 WakeDetails           DriverReason:NUB.SPMI0Sw3IRQ - DriverDetails:                              
DriverReason:nub-spmi0.0x02 - DriverDetails:                               
DriverReason:rtc - DriverDetails:                                          
2024-10-03 04:50:18 -0600 HibernateStats        hibmode=0 standbydelaylow=0 standbydelayhigh=0                                        720           

2024-10-03 04:31:58 -0600 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt DataFrame ARPT/UserActivity Assertion Using AC (Charge:0%) 67 secs   
2024-10-03 04:31:58 -0600 WakeDetails           DriverReason:SMC.OutboxNotEmpty - DriverDetails:                           
DriverReason:smc.70070000 - DriverDetails:                                 
DriverReason:wifibt - DriverDetails:                                       
DriverReason:DataFrame - DriverDetails:0800450001bb0ecf4000330687f1113990580a0103eb1467d0e5c732472
DriverReason:ARPT - DriverDetails:                                         

2024-10-03 06:17:14 -0600 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 smc.70160000 USB2_wake/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:0%) 725 secs  
2024-10-03 06:17:14 -0600 WakeDetails           DriverReason:SMC.OutboxNotEmpty - DriverDetails:                           
DriverReason:smc.70070000 - DriverDetails:                                 
DriverReason:smc.70160000 - DriverDetails:                                 
DriverReason:USB2_wake - DriverDetails:                                    
2024-10-03 06:17:14 -0600 HibernateStats        hibmode=0 standbydelaylow=0 standbydelayhigh=0                                        729           

(The last one was the first one which was actually me; I did not include all the logs here, but these are representative).
I can't figure out what is waking the system up or, more importantly, how to get it to stop. I don't care if it's going from Deep Idle to Dark Wake, but waking my displays up over and over and over again is completely unacceptable.
How do I find the cause of this and, more importantly, stop it?
Some other details:

The reboot (power off section on -4 around 7pm) was the upgrade from macOS 15.0 to 15.0.1
"Prevent automatic sleeping when the display is off" is off
"Wake for network access" is off
"Start up automatically after a power failure" is off
2023 Mac Studio, M2 Max
Displays are both ViewSonic: VP2785-4K (via HDMI) and VP2786-4K (via USB-C/DP to DisplayPort)

USB tree:
+-o Root  <class IORegistryEntry, id 0x100000100, retain 37>
  +-o AppleT8112USBXHCI@03000000  <class AppleT8112USBXHCI, id 0x1000003d1, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (397 ms), retain 54>
  | +-o Macally ACEKEY Series USB Keyboard@03100000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000b95, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (360 ms), retain 35>
  +-o AppleT8112USBXHCI@02000000  <class AppleT8112USBXHCI, id 0x1000003b8, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (29 ms), retain 37>
  +-o AppleT8112USBXHCI@00000000  <class AppleT8112USBXHCI, id 0x1000003db, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (20 ms), retain 37>
  +-o AppleT8112USBXHCI@01000000  <class AppleT8112USBXHCI, id 0x1000003c0, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (22 ms), retain 43>
  | +-o USB-C To DP Cable@01100000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000c0b, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (13 ms), retain 18>
  +-o AppleEmbeddedUSBXHCIASMedia3142@08000000  <class AppleEmbeddedUSBXHCIASMedia3142, id 0x100000aa7, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (499 ms), retain 318>
    +-o USB3 Gen2 Hub@08100000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000bab, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (65 ms), retain 30>
    | +-o 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub@08130000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000bc9, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (33 ms), retain 33>
    | | +-o 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub@08131000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000be3, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (16 ms), retain 32>
    | +-o 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub@08140000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000bcb, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (33 ms), retain 33>
    |   +-o 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub@08141000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000be5, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (17 ms), retain 32>
    +-o USB2 Hub@08300000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000bbb, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (434 ms), retain 30>
      +-o 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub@08330000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000bfd, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (25 ms), retain 33>
      | +-o 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub@08331000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000c1c, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (17 ms), retain 32>
      +-o 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub@08340000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000c09, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (403 ms), retain 35>
        +-o 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub@08341000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000c28, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (81 ms), retain 33>
        | +-o Scarlett 2i2 USB@08341200  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000c51, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (66 ms), retain 31>
        +-o USB Receiver@08342000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000c38, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (364 ms), retain 34>
        +-o SpaceMouse Compact@08344000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000c41, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (347 ms), retain 29>


Nicely researched and documented question! I like that graph and am curious how you generated it.

Thanks! I had a python script analyze the logs. I also have my own home automation system which knows when I'm home or not, so I pulled the presence data from it.

That seems like it would be a great writeup/blogpost if you ever had time.
